# Changing the required field validator error message with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a required field validator with a generic error message; using java script I want to change the error according to some conditions

I am using this code

```
    var RfvInternalNotes = document.getElementById("RfvInternalNotes");
    RfvInternalNotes.innerText = "";
    RfvInternalNotes.innerText = "Please enter a reason for assigning this question to a different person";
```

no javascript error but my custom message is not displayed, instead is displayed the error message I set into the required field validator properties. I have also tried this

```
RfvInternalNotes.ErrorMessage= "Please enter a reason for assigning this question to a different person";
```

but no joy ; any help ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem; I was calling that function also somewhere else; is working now

Answer (score 0):

I think you can better use Custom Validator and use its ClientValidationFunction functions that may somehow look like:

```
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1" 
          ClientValidationFunction="MyClientValidationFunction" />

<script language="javascript">
      function MyClientValidationFunction(sender, args){

               sender.errormessage = "Validation failed";

               args.IsValid = true; // false based upon your conditions...
               return;        
       }
</script>
```

[Client Validation Function Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx)

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try now but I am still interested in knowing how to change a required field validator message in JavaSCript.

Comment: I am using this code now

    
'<asp:CustomValidator ID="CvStatusChanged" runat="server"
ClientValidationFunction="EnableDisableStatusValidator"  
ClientIDMode="Static"
ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"/>'

and this javascrpit function

function EnableDisableStatusValidator(sender, args)
{

}

but the sender is undefined

Comment: added the controltovalidate property but the sender is still undefined

Comment: found the problem; I was calling that function also somewhere else; is working now

Comment: still the same problem; after I use sender.textContent = sender.innerText = sender.innerHTML = sender.ErrorMessage = "Please enter a reason for changing this question status"; the error message is still the default one I set of "N/A"